# How to share a connection in Guacamole with multiple users each having their own username and ssh key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

In Apache Guacamole, is there a way for multiple users to share a single connection while each using their own credentials (username, SSH key and passphrase) in order to avoid re-defining all the existing connections for each user?

I'm thinking of some sort of user-specific parameters that would override the ones defined at the connection level.

Looking at the DB, I can see a guacamole_sharing_profile_parameter but it doesn't seem to be intended for that and I wasn't able to find anything by googling it.

Thanks!

Comment: if anything fails, you can miss use `screen` to share with into the session

Answer (score 0):

assign the connection to a user group and add users to that user group that way users in that user group can access  that connection.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a 'shared connection group' and adding users to this group, but still no luck.  Has anyone else cracked the nut on this problem??